# How to add ContentEditor Web Part in Page Layout?

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, content-editor-web-part

I Want to add Content Editor in my Page. This has to be done in Page layout. Hence any OOTB solution is not suitable. Any Suggestions?

```
<WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart
                webpart="true"
                runat="server"
               _WebPartId="{D2E2E9C9-554F-4C66-8AB8-07B6EE9D781D}"
               Title="Article Author"
               Description="Web Part Layout"
               PartImageLarge=""
               PartOrder="2"
               ID="g_d18920b4_6273_4d72_97ef_75404fdf7155"
               ChromeType="TitleOnly"
               ContentLink=""
                __WebPartId="{D18920B4-6273-4D72-97EF-75404FDF7155}">
               </WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
```

Comment: Are you adding it through SharePoint Designer
Maybe try this:
[Adding CEWP to page layout](http://techtodev.azurewebsites.net/2016/01/25/adding-pre-configured-web-parts-to-a-page-layout/)

Comment: I have to add in page layout not in page

Comment: I have Created one page layout which one i use in my Content pages.  in that layout i want to add one content editor using that content editor i have to change my pages content. guide me  how to add content editor in Page Layout????

Comment: Does the link that devnation posted not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Content Editor web part using Elements.xml file of the Page Layout module in Visual Studio.

You can add CEWP using `AllUsersWebPart`. Please add below code inside Pagelayout file tag as shown below:

```
<File Path="PageLayoutModule\DepartmentPageLayout.aspx" Url="PageLayoutModule/DepartmentPageLayout.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE" Level="Published">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Department PageLayout"/>
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
      <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/BlankWebPartPage.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/BlankWebPartPage.png" />
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D4;#" />

      <AllUsersWebPart WebPartOrder="1" WebPartZoneID="Overview">
        <![CDATA[

<WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Overview Content</Title>
  <FrameType>None</FrameType>
  <ChromeType>None</ChromeType>
  <Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>wp</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>0</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
  <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>
  <ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
  <Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor">

             &lt;div class=&quot;department-overview&quot;&gt;
            /// Your HTML Code here.
            &lt;/div&gt;

  </Content>
        <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
        </WebPart>

        ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>

    </File>
```